# how to read excel data without manually telling the cells

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, microsoft.office.interop.excel

My code when ran, opens a form and when that form opens, it opens and reads data from a excel spreadsheet. During the initial load, it reads the specific data from it's current cells. To test the theory of reading extra data, I manually re-read the data using a button and calling specific cells. Here is my code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test_read_data_from_excel
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFile();

        }

        public void OpenFile()
        {
            Excel excel = new Excel(@"Test.xlsx", 1);
            textBox1.Text = excel.ReadCell(1, 0);
            textBox2.Text = excel.ReadCell(1, 1);
            textBox3.Text = excel.ReadCell(3, 2);
            
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm = new Form2();
            frm.Show();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Excel excel = new Excel(@"Test.xlsx", 1);
            textBox1.Text = excel.ReadCell(2, 0);
            textBox2.Text = excel.ReadCell(2, 1);
            textBox3.Text = excel.ReadCell(4 , 2);
        }
    }

}
```

How can I get the form to automatically read the data and then every 10 seconds display the next line or cells of data? P.S. I used a button to check to see if the reading of the next line of data or cells works correctly.

Comment: My answer should help with the timer aspect of this, but I am confused about your Excel code. Are you using microsoft.office.interop.excel? I don't see it in your using statements. I also don't recognize that excel code from an interop perspective. For interop, you would have to initialize your application, workbook, then the worksheet, THEN you could get the cell data. Any chance you could clarify?

Answer (score 0):

For the timer functionality, try something like this:

```
private void InitializeTimer()  
{  
    // Call this procedure when the application starts.  
    // Set to 10 seconds.  
    Timer1.Interval = 10000; // .Interval is in milliseconds
    Timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer1_Tick);  
  
    // Enable timer.  
    Timer1.Enabled = true;  
}  
  
private void Timer1_Tick(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{  
   //Call any excel code you want to run every 10 seconds here  
}
```